# Two Slices for Nested List

Tags: python

There is one nested list [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4,4]].

I would like to iterate the list by three slices. I belong to [0, 3], j=i-1, k=i-2

For example:

```
     slice 1: [3, 3], [4, 4]
     slice 2: [2, 2], [3, 3]
     slice 3: [1, 1], [2, 2]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you clarify how you determine which elements should be shown on which line? What is `j` and `k` about?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
s = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4,4]]
new_s = {"slice {}".format(len(s)-i-1):[s[i], s[i+1]] for i in range(len(s)-1)}
```

Output:

```
{'slice 1': [[3, 3], [4, 4]], 'slice 3': [[1, 1], [2, 2]], 'slice 2': [[2, 2], [3, 3]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) you can create that output like:

#### Code:

```
new_data = list(zip(reversed(data[:-1]), reversed(data)))
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]]
new_data = list(zip(reversed(data[:-1]), reversed(data)))
print(new_data)
```

And if you want a dict from that:

```
new_data = {'slice_{}'.format(i): d for i, d in
            enumerate(zip(reversed(data[:-1]), reversed(data)), 1)}
print(new_data)
```

#### Results:

```
[([3, 3], [4, 4]), ([2, 2], [3, 3]), ([1, 1], [2, 2])]

{'slice_1': ([3, 3], [4, 4]), 'slice_2': ([2, 2], [3, 3]), 'slice_3': ([1, 1], [2, 2])}
```

Comment: You can get rid of one of the `reversed` calls by inverting, well, everything :) `new_data = list(reversed(zip(data, data[:-1])))`.

Comment: @chepner, `TypeError: 'zip' object is not reversible`

Comment: You need an extra `list` wrapper for Python 3. `new_data = list(reversed(list(zip...))))`. (Which, admittedly, makes it a less exciting change.)

Comment: But then you end up building an extra list.  Hmm..  So many possibilities.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Depending on what the OP wants, the *outer* list might not be necessary, e.g., `for x, y in reversed(list(zip(data, data[:-1])))`. The best answer will depend on what is actually needed. It's somewhat annoying that `reversed` doesn't work with an arbitrary iterator, although in principle I get why it doesn't.